# What does the Web settings stand for in Facebook App settings?

Tags: facebook

FB's settings page seems to have changed drastically and the guides on net are outdated. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

What does the "Site Url" and "Site Domain" stand for, as I have already provided my Canvas Url on another page and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for web apps and websites that integrate or interact with Facebook.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

*Site Url* is the main URL of your website/ web app

*Site Domain* indicts which domain authentication is to be enable on for your application - typically this will be the same domain as your site URL